# Specifying column to input data in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python. As such, I would greatly appreciate some advice on issues relating to manipulting data in CSV files. (1) In my code below, how to I specify Data1 and Data2 to be inserted into column 9 and column 10 in my CSV file? (2) Also, for future reference, how do I specify row and column to extract data or to write into in a csv file?

```
file1  = open (fileA.csv, 'rb')
reader1 = csv.reader(file1)

outfile = open ('fileB.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

next(reader1, None)  # skip the headers

for col in reader1:
    subset1 = [float(x) for x in col[3:6]]
    Max1 = max (subset1)
    Min1 = min (subset1)
    Data1 = str(Max1 - Min1)
    subset2 = [float(x) for x in col[6:9]]
    Max2 = max (subset2)
    Min2 = min (subset2)
    Data2 = str(Max2 - Min2)
    ........????            

    writer.writerow(Data)


 file1.close()
 outfile.close()
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do

```
writer.writerow(col[:9] + [Data1, Data2] + col[9:])
```

(although I must say that `col` is an unfortunate choice for a variable name since it will hold a row, not a column of CSV data)...